# Getting application crash during opening a local pdf file on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

 [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About" ofType: @"pdf"];

    NSLog(@"%@", path);

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

    [_webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Comment: could you explain that where it crash? what is the message? may be the addressing is not correct. give more info

Comment: I have a navigation controller whenever i pop up controllers and then push one view controller with webview as IBOutlet on it. It crashes on the above code i guess but when i comment the above code it just run smoothly.

Comment: That's exactly how I display my PDFs.  Can you give a bit more detail on the error message?

Comment: "Jul 16 15:48:45 unknown com.apple.debugserver-64[579] <Warning>: 3 [0243/0303]: error: ::mach_vm_read ( task = 0x1603, addr = 0x00000000, size = 512, data => 0x00000000, dataCnt => 0 ) err = (os/kern) invalid address (0x00000001)" This is what i'm getting on the device's log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some other issue not related to the pdf loading over web view. I cross checked and found the actual cause of crash. Anyways thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

just use following code for open PDF in web view

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About" ofType:@"pdf"]; 
[self.webVctr loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

And check it out the PDF is exist or not?

This thinks may helping to you

Happy codeing..

Comment: Can you create the property of the webview controller

Comment: I din't created the property of webview controller. I don't need to access it from outside the class then why should i need to create a property of any controller or variable ? I'm just using the IBOutlet of UIWebView which is connected to the nib file's Control

Comment: can you please show me the error log then after i can understand the problem. :-(

Comment: Jul 16 15:48:45 unknown com.apple.debugserver-64[579] <Warning>: 3 [0243/0303]: error: ::mach_vm_read ( task = 0x1603, addr = 0x00000000, size = 512, data => 0x00000000, dataCnt => 0 ) err = (os/kern) invalid address (0x00000001)" This is what i'm getting on the device's log

Comment: As my understanding  the problem is not the webview pdf load but issue is some thing else... First of comment all pdf load call and run the application and let me know the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13929/discussion-between-neon-samuel-and-slim-shaddy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in the

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: i had changed my answer, hope this will help